# c++ constant function declaration variants?

Tags: c++

Are all of the below declarations the same? If so, what is the standard way to declare a constant function?

```
const SparseMatrix transpose();

SparseMatrix transpose() const;

const SparseMatrix transpose() const;
```

Comment: Here's a hint: They're all different.

Comment: But the first is more different, as the other two are ambiguous.

Comment: There's also `SparseMatrix const transpose() const` and `SparseMatrix const transpose()` to consider.

Comment: What semantics are you actually looking for? A small example might help.

Comment: The last two aren't functions. They're at best *non-static member* functions of some nebulous ambient class or union, but you're not telling us that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The const on the left of the function name means the object that is returned cannot be modified. The const on the right means the method is apart of a class and does not modify any of its data members. Unless or course any of its data members are declared with the `mutable` keyword, in which case modification thereof is permitted despite a `const` guard.

The placement of the `const` keyword is unimportant when the return type of the function is  of non-pointer type:

```
 T const f(); // same as const T f();
```

However, note that the placement of the `const` keyword matters when using a *pointer* as the return type. For example:

```
const T* f();
```

This method returns a pointer to a const `T`. That is, what it points to is immutable. So you cannot do an assignment through a dereference of the returned pointer:

```
T* x = f();

*x = y; // error: assignment of read-only location '*(const T*)x'
```

When const is placed on the immediate right of the return type (that is a pointer), it means the pointer is const and cannot be changed.

```
T* const f();

int main()
{
    T* x const;

    x = f(); // error: assignment of read-only variable 'x'
}
```

Furthermore, if we have `const` on *both* sides of a pointer return type, and have `const` denoting "no modification of class members", then it's read as the following:

```
const T* const f() const;
```

> A const member function named `f` that returns a const pointer to a const `T`

Comment: It can change `mutable` members

Answer (score 4):

The first one will return a `SparseMatrix` that is const and cant be changed.

The second one declares a function that returns a `SparseMatrix` and assures the function will not change any class variables (assuming it is a member function, otherwise it wouldnt make sense with this deceleration) except for mutable members.

The final one does both.

Comment: Can you clarify that it's a _member_ function, and that it won't modify (non-mutable) members _of the instance of the class it is part of_.

Comment: @MooingDuck Are you saying to change my answer because it can be misread?

Comment: I think so, you need to specify that the second and third ones only apply to non-static member functions.

Comment: @Ben: basically, yeah.  The answer currently can be interpreted as that the function won't change any members of the `SparseMatrix` it's returning, which I admit would make no sense, but I would just prefer if the answer were totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

1） return a const value
2) const function, no member changes inside it
3) 1)+2)